# Menu font size of some applications too bigger or too smaller than system fonts

Tags: fonts, ubuntu-gnome

I have been experiencing some weird behavior regarding the font size of some desktop applications in Ubuntu Gnome 16.04. First, Google Chrome's fonts of tabs and bookmarks are suddenly giant after an upgrade. I found some related questions about this problem with Chrome specifically, however this now happens to the menu fonts of other desktop applications that I use: [Skype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cj63u.png), [Mendeley Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRUBO.png), Wmail... With all of them the menu fonts are too big or too small compared to the system's fonts. Also, their font does not change if I use the Gnome Tweak Tool scaling option. My question then is how can I have the same font size in these applications? I think it is important to remark that this behavior started to happen after some upgrade of each application.

And sorry for sending only two screenshots, this is my first question, so my reputation does not allow me to send more :)

Thanks in advance!